# Find is returning "find: .: Permission denied", but I am not searching in 

Tags: linux, bash, sudo

I have an enormous shell script that I am troubleshooting.  I often run the script from my home directory with a `sudo`.  Whenever a `find` is executed, I see this error:

`find: .: Permission denied`

It is true that root does not have access to my home directory (which is the current working directory or `.` in the error above), but I'm not asking `find` to do anything in my home directory and would rather it leave it alone entirely.

To really drive the point home I ran this:

`sudo find /dev -maxdepth 1 -type f`

and still get the same error.  If the `-type -f` is removed the error is appended to the end of the expected results.  Of course, if I `cd /dev` there is no error..probably since root has access to `/dev`.  Even though I don't think it's causing problems, it makes the script look buggy.  How can I prevent the script from showing these errors?

Comment: `root` *should* be able to access your home directory if the `sudo find` command specifies it: that's what 'root' means.

Comment: @pavium Unless the home directory is, for example, mounted over NFS with the `root_squash` option (default).

Comment: @Bolo is correct.  The home directory is externally mounted.  `root` does not have permissions on it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I ran:

```
strace find /dev -maxdepth 1
```

on GNU/Linux (Ubuntu) and it turns out that `find` uses `fchdir` syscall to traverse the directory tree and finally executes `fchdir` to go back to the original working directory.  Here's a snippet:

```
open(".", O_RDONLY|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK|O_LARGEFILE|O_DIRECTORY|O_NOFOLLOW) = 4
fchdir(4)                               = 0

... irrelevant ...

write(1, "/dev\n", 5)                   = 5
open("/dev", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_LARGEFILE|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 5
fcntl64(5, F_GETFD)                     = 0x1 (flags FD_CLOEXEC)
fchdir(5)                               = 0

... potentially more fchdirs ...

fchdir(4)                               = 0
close(4)                                = 0
```

My hint?  `cd /tmp` (or some other fully accessible directory) before running `find`.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I wish there was some sort of switch to turn off that behavior.

Answer (score 3):

Add a `cd /` to the start of the script. Unless you `source` it, the script is run in a sub-shell, so your own `$PWD` will not be changed. If you *do* source it, either store `$PWD` at the start and `cd -- "$PWD"` at the end, or simply `cd -` if you don't do any other `cd`s in the script.

Answer (score 1):

Try redirecting stderr.  For example, you could throw it away:

```
find /dev 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I still want to see the output of stderr.

Comment: very old answer, but this is what I stumbled upon while searching. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/42842 is an answer that retains the rest of stderr.

TL;DR `find . 2>&1 | grep -v 'Permission denied'`