# sudo find Permission Denied

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I am using ubuntu xenial from WSL, and I got an error when I used this command:

```
mysql -uroot -p
```

So I searched for solution, and the solution was here:
[error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11990708/error-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run-mysqld-mysq/11990813)

But I got another error. When I use this command:

```
sudo find / -type s
```

It sais my permission is denied.

```
find: ‘/mnt/c/$Recycle.Bin/S-1-5-18’: Permission denied
find: ‘/mnt/c/$Recycle.Bin/S-1-5-21-2991848659-3455357464-4000823703-500’: Permission denied
find: ‘/mnt/c/$Recycle.Bin/S-1-5-21-3789379520-1944576062-3837406785-1000’: Permission denied
find: ‘/mnt/c/$Recycle.Bin/S-1-5-21-3789379520-1944576062-3837406785-500’: Permission denied
find: ‘/mnt/c/$Recycle.Bin/S-1-5-21-528926963-23163656-3807874771-500’: Permission denied
find: ‘/mnt/c/Config.Msi’: Permission denied

...
```

But I am the root.

What should I do to solve this error?

Comment: Post your exact error message(s)

Comment: add more information. In the meantime, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5791651/find-is-returning-find-permission-denied-but-i-am-not-searching-in might help

Comment: Those errors are from (i believe) a windows drive mounted on /mnt/c ... I wouldn't worry about those errors.  The original problem (cant connect) - ensure your mysql server is actually running and that the socket is defined in the same location for both the client and the server (check the my.cnf files .. socket=/path/to/socket).

Comment: My error message says "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'", but there is no directory /var/run/mysqld.